# Union Types with interfaces, recognize only shared property

Tags: typescript

I would like to use two interfaces as in a `Union Types` in TypeScript, but as you can see in the simple example below, I can not check to see what type the parameter is and I can just access the properties that the two interfaces share.  Do you have any suggestions on what should I do?

[image: simple example]

Comment: Please read [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#unions-with-common-fields), you are allowed to get only common fields. If you want to narrow the type, you should use either [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) or [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a [discriminated unions](https://css-tricks.com/typescript-discriminated-unions/).

```
interface Foo {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   type: "Foo";
}

interface Bar {
   id: string;
   phoneNumber: number;
   type: "Bar";
}

function baz(input: Foo | Bar) {
   if(input.type === "Bar") {
      input.phoneNumber 
   }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDED2nUG9iqEgAmAXKgM4QzgDmA3AYWAgLZTlU1gNOoQBPAA4dUAIiyYxjAL7BQkWIhSoAQghh4%20JTtTqNCqIQAtMYKADkArqwBGscmBv2YBwoJHkx6mNOBzgOCswJAgQM1RbBAAvAApwISsIcklUAB81DQBKLUMQOHiwRIgAOg80AF4q8R8xHPxDPKKkkpMzS2dYVD45GSA)

Answer (score 2):

`input` has the type `Foo | Bar`, which means, at this point, for TypeScript, it can be one of them, but can't tell further. So it only knows `id`, the shared property. You should have a type checking. I would do something like this:

```
interface Foo{
  id:string;
  name:string;
  type:"Foo"

}

interface Bar{
  id:string;
  phoneNumber:string;
  type:"Bar"

}

function bas(input : Foo| Bar){
  if(input.type === "Bar"){
    input.phoneNumber
  }else{
    input.name
  }
}
```

Notice I'm using this `type` propriety. Here a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0G8BQznAAmAXAM5hSgDmA3HsiHALYRkXV35gCeADqwCIM6AThwBfMaEixEKAEJwoufETaUQterwAW6EBAByAVyYAjaOo70e-YgMVRREsTGMgEYYPuRm4pAApQXmMwZGI0TAAfZEcAShUCGCCQELAAOlsUAF5c5AclAQT6VVTQ9N19I1MLKHpxCAAbUghE0rT0xhZ6iSA) if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your interface from a basic interface with `id` like so:

```
interface IdAble {
  id: string;
}

interface Foo extends IdAble {
  name: string;
}

interface Bar extends IdAble {
  phoneNumber: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [narrow down](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type first before assigning non-shared attributes.
There are two solutions you can choose based on your situation:

1. Create a common attribute and give it different values to distinguish between them.

```js
// firt solution
interface Foo {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   type: "foo";
}

interface Bar {
   id: string;
   phoneNumber: number;
   type: "bar";
}

function baz(input: Foo | Bar) {
   if (input.type === "bar") {
      input.phoneNumber
   }
   if (input.type === "foo") {
      input.name
   }
}
```

2. Check if the key is in the object.

```js
// second solution
interface Foo2 {
   id: string;
   name: string;
}

interface Bar2 {
   id: string;
   phoneNumber: number;
}

function baz2(input: Foo2 | Bar2) {
   if ('phoneNumber' in input) {
      input.phoneNumber // the type will point to Bar2.
   }
   if ('name' in input) {
      input.name // the type will point to Foo2.
   }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIDMEsCcBdwGcD2AbArvaKB2xpd4BTWSAQwGNjwAxFFcAb2HDegBMAuZeWQgOYBuVm1zkAtsR5I+gkW3DwAngAdp4AESQGmkQF9gBIqQrVwAIXKxmo8Jxlzcwu6oAWeYgDkMEgEakPLi+AbAKbCrqPJp+1nrAhsCQGLiU2HjgsQBeABSEqlg89IwAPpbWAJS2itCQ4Hm4BfAAdJE0ALydWrGwmlUsijWNWM3unj7+pHaGNXUNTa1qHV3auv12QwviUtMJRmDIxJR4HMjoWDj4hCRkVDTFAEzV7Ny8-M7h4Nsasu8uiddTHdyrAngMXo4-p8xrhvCFAl94WE9kkUmlLplyFkHvNCnQGE8ylZQetZvUAOQwuGTWDk+y4elNUmDRkjKkTULgA7wNw0NrgADu0DQaHAqhQ1yUjGJD2auzJOXJ3zphFZ8GZg3yI2+XIgPL5S0FwtF4sl8EYjzlikM+iAA)